# I need a complex analysis proof I attempted I checked!

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose I wanted to show that if $g$ is analytic, and $|g|$ is constant on some disk like neighborhood $z = z_{0}$, then $g$ would also be constant.

Attempt: Let $g = u + iv$. Then, $|g|^2 = u^2 + v^2$. If I differentiated with respect to $x$ and $y$ I would get $2uu_{x} + 2vv_{x} = 0$ and $2uu_{y} + 2vv_{y} = 0$. Notice how we can use the Cauchy Riemann equations to rewrite it as $2uu_{x} - 2vv_{y} = 0$ and $2uu_{y} + 2vv_{x} = 0$. From here, this says that $u^2 + v^2 = 0 \Rightarrow u = v = 0 \Rightarrow g = u + iv$ is constant.

How does this look?

Comment: I do not see how you concluded that $u^2 + v^2 = 0$.

Comment: Depending on what you know, you could also note that if $g$ were non-constant, then it would need to send the disc to an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, but since it's sitting inside some circle $|z|=R$, this is impossible. So, it's constant.

Comment: I don't see how you use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to obtain $2uu_x-2vv_y = 0$ and $2uu_y+2vv_x = 0$ from $2uu_x + 2vv_x = 0$ and $2uu_y + 2vv_y = 0$. Of course that's true, since under the hypothesis, we have $u_x = u_y = v_x = v_y = 0$, but I don't see a direct transformation.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of this as a linear system of equations for the unknowns $u_x=v_y$, $u_y=-v_x$, you should see that *either* $u^2+v^2=0$ *or* $u_x=u_y=0$.